question regarding modelling motion of particle using a step function
I have a particle which starts off with a velocity of 30 meter per second and reduces its velocity by 5 meter per second instantly every two seconds i thought a good way to model this kind of motion would be via the floor function i came up with the following function.
$$f(x) = floor(-x/2)+31$$
This is good and models the v-t graph of a particle which does the same thing as the above particle but reduces its speed by 1 meter per second after every 2 seconds how do i modify this function to match my case.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

$f(x) = 30 - 5 \operatorname{floor}\left(\frac x2\right)$
